# Button height dynamic

Tags: android

I want to create my button height using drawable xml file and it should also resize dynamically with my layout, so that it can support any Android device.

Currently I am using RelativeLayout with match_parent height. I want to put a set of 3X4 buttons in this layout and should automatically resize with the device height.

I am not able to resize it properly when I use dp values. If I resize the button for large res device, it is not working fine for 240X320 res device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do what you want with the Android layout classes. You aren't completely clear, but it sounds like [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) is what you want.

The default Android UI element should deal well with being sized dynamically; if you have a custom drawable asset, you'll want to make an appropriate 9-patch image at each of the common display densities (so that it not only resizes correctly, but looks good on a range of devices).

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been thinking about this very topic, and I think I can help you. If I understand you correctly, you would like to have your application dynamically resize your buttons depending on the screen size. In order to do that you can use binding and a converter. If you bind your button's height (and width if you prefer) to the page's height (and width) you can use a converter to convert the value to a percentage of the screen size. If you like, I can provide you with some sample code.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the size of the display `Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();` and set the sizes dinamically.

Or, you can make various sizes of your images.